# codeigniter login after email verified

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am trying to make sure user can login after confirming their email verification in which STATUS in the database changes from 0 to 1. how do I log users in based on the change of status in the database. Thanks in advance

MODEL:

```
   public function login($username, $password){
    //validation
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        return $result->row(0)->id;

    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
   public function login(){
    $data['title'] = 'Login';

    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation-> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('users/login', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {

        // fetching user
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
        //password
    $password = ($this->input->post('password'));

    //login user
    $user_id = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);

    if($user_id){
        //creating session
        $user_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'username' => $username,
            'logged_in' => TRUE,

        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                // Set message to be sent
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_login', 'Welcome');
    redirect('posts');
    } else {
        // Set message to be sent
    $this->session->set_flashdata('login_fail', 'Login Failed');
    redirect('users/login'); 
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure how you create your password dont have plain text in database http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php Then to verify it use a callback function http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: i know I'm just concerned about the login now. i would definitely hash the password

Comment: you question is unclear. What you want to do? are you want to check user is verified at login or after registration user should verify the email and then user can login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how to check that user is verified or not then this should be your model code:

```
public function login($username, $password){

    $query = $this->db
            ->select('your_column')
            ->where(['user_email' => $user_name, 'user_password' => $user_password])
            ->where('user_verification_status','1')
            ->get('users');

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
                $result = $query->row_array();
                return $result;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }

}
```

OR if you want to verify user after registration then you should follow this step:

1. When Someone Register in your system and when you are saving that user data in your `registration table` at that time you should use entered email and send the verified link on user email.
2. In that verification link you have structured it as when user click on it it came to your verification page and at that time you should change the status of user and show message that user is verified and now you can login into the system.
3. And as the model code given in the answer you should check that user have verified or not.

Please let me know if you need more detail regarding the user verification.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to verify that the user who's trying to login is verified (if am getting your query right).

for this you can just add another where statement in your query builder while checking username and password. So your model will be like

```
public function login($username, $password){
    //validation
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $this->db->where('status', '1');

    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        return $result->row(0)->id;

    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

So now even if user have submitted correct login details but haven't verified his account yet, he'll be unable to login.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have the verification system ready and you're changing the status column in db from 0 to 1.
Using the code below, you will be able to perform login based on that requirement by informing the user in case he isn't verified.

> Model (return with proper errors):

```
public function login($username, $password){

  $this->db->where('username', $username);
  $this->db->where('password', $password);

  $result = $this->db->get('users');
  if($result->num_rows() == 1){
     $user=$result->row_array();
     if($user['status']==1){ // user is verified
       $response['error']="false";
       $response['user']=$user['id'];
     }
     else{ // not verified
        $response['error']="true";
        $response['error_msg']="Please verify your email first!";
     }

  } 
  else { // credentials mismatch
     $response['error']="true";
     $response['error_msg']="Invalid username or password";
  }
  return $response;
}
```

> Controller (use returned array from model)

```
//login user
$login = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
if($login['error']){ // login failed
   $this->session->set_flashdata('login_fail', $login['error']);
   redirect('users/login');
}
else{ // success
    $user=$login['user'];
    // do whatever you want after successful login
}
```